# import and use a PyPi package directly from a software packaged with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, pypi

Greetings to the community.

I want to add a functionality to my software but from my research I could not determine if it is possible or not.

My software written in python is packaged using PyInstaller 6.3. I use the onedir option and beginning from PyInstaller 6.0 this will create an executable and a directory named "_internal" where it puts all the files from the imported packages. Now, the software has the capability to read a user's custom python functions from an uploaded .py file in order to perform some mathematical computations. Inside this external py file, the user can import and use only the packages that were included during the PyInstaller packaging process (the ones in the _internal directory).

The question is if it is possible from within my software to dynamically install (using PIP) packages from PyPi. I have been able to do it manually, i.e, I install the package in a local venv, then I go to the site-packages directory and i copy the directory of my package to the _internal directory created by PyInstaller.

So it is a long shot to believe that if I manage to package the pip executable in my software, I can invoke it with subprocess and the Pypi package and direct its install to _internal ?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `pip` is python module - so you can use `import pip`. It should have some method to run it like in console - but I don't remember function. Maybe `pip.main(['install', 'some_module'])`. Or you can use `subprocess.run( ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install',  'some_module'] )`

Comment: Out of curiosity, your usecase looks more suitable for a programming framework rather than an executable. Are you sure your target audience really needs an executable?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I am not 100% sure what you mean by programming framework but yes it is an installable software running through an executable.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is python module - so you can use

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'some_module'])

pip.main(['unistall', 'some_module'])

pip.main(['list'])

pip.main(['freeze'])
```

---

Eventually you can use `python` to run this module as subprocess

```
subprocess.run( ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install',  'some_module'] )

subprocess.run( ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'list'] )

subprocess.run( ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze'] )

subprocess.run( ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'uninstall',  'some_module'] )
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make sure you can use `sys.executable` instead of `python`

```
subprocess.run( [sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install',  'some_module'] )
```

Comment: well the actual question is if this procedure is possible though an installable software not from a console where you have already created and activated a venv and the commands you propose know where to put the package.

Comment: `pyinstaller` creates self-extracting `zip` file (with extension `exe`) with `python.exe`, modules, and your code. When you run `exe` then it create temporary file, and it extract `python.exe` (and rest) to this folder and it runs `python.exe your_script.py` - so it should work. Eventually It may need `/full/path/to/extacted/python.exe` and `sys,executable` should gives this path. But frankly, I would simply try to run it instead of asking. It is faster then waiting for answers.

Comment: BTW: but all this has one problem (as for me). When you close `exe` then it deletes temporary folder with all installed modules and it will have to install module every time when you run `exe`. So it may need time. Or you would have to create some folder outside temporary folder and install in this folder (`pip install --target=...`) and always add this folder to `sys.path` before importing modules.